# Why Should I always follow the rules of functional harmony?

Tags: chords, harmony, composition, functional-harmony

I have used functional harmony many times in my compositions to write chord progressions with success, however there are times when using functional harmony doesn't sound good to me and others when I have written chord progressions that don't follow the rules of functional harmony and still sound good, at least to my untrained ears.

So, why should I try to always follow the rules for functional harmony when writing chord progressions?

Comment: Maybe the question should be prefaced by the word WHY.

Comment: You'd be shocked how many chord progressions follow functional harmony, let alone common practice period harmony, even if they don't sound like they do at first blush. For example, the chord progression G-B-C-Cm-G can be explained with common practice period harmony as I-V/vi-VI/vi = IV-iv-I.

Answer (score 5):

Those rules are more like guidelines. If all music had to stick to the 'rules', it would have run out of new ideas years ago!

You can do whatever you like with music, chord progressions, etc., and have people give their opinions on the results. In the past, composers have 'thrown out the rule book' (whatever that may be!), and produced weird and wonderful compositions. Some just weird, some wonderful! It will depend on the genre used, and your targetted audience, as to whether it is accepted, but the old adage - if it sounds good, it probably is - usually rings true. Some may question your motives, but by 'breaking the rules', you're going to be pushing the boundaries of an art in the right direction.

Comment: I’m so glad to see the word “art” in your answer, +1. Too many people get hung up on what is “right and wrong” once they start reading their first music theory or harmony book.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Functional harmony is great.  So is non-functional harmony.  It's good to trek the mountains heading for a destination, it's good to sit by the lake watching the colours of the light on the water.   And it's good to mix the two.

When you find something that sounds interesting it can be productive to analyse WHY it sounds interesting, and that won't always lead to a functional explanation (so stop knocking yourselves out, guys!).  Or just give it a name, so you can find it again next time.

'Why' can be a very tricky question.  Why does G7 want to resolve (functionally) to C?  Because it contains the tritone, F-B, which wants to resolve to E-C. Yes, but WHY does a tritone want to...

I wonder if you'll manage to do without the basic functional concept of a tonic?   It can be done...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, as the scientists like to say, [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong). And that is remarkably good news!

It is incredibly important to remember that above all else, music is subjective, not objective. Music theory is descriptive, not prescriptive - it attempts to explain post-hoc why music sounds good but cannot predict with certainty whether certain effects will be effective. It is very tempting to treat music theory the same way we treat math or physics, where it has firmly-established rules and a rigorous nature, that following those rules will produce good music, and that breaking those rules will produce music that lacks artistic merit or sounds cacophonous. But this is a serious mistake to make.

Artistic taste and a good ear are the true judges of music. Music theory is just a tool.

Treating music theory as more rigorous than it truly is is an easy mistake to make. There's actually a surprising and frankly dark history to it. It's not a mistake one comes to because of laziness or lack of imagination, but because highly-respected people who really should have known better have pushed absurd ideas for decades. In the twentieth century, when the United States saw communism as an existential threat and was mired in profound systematic racism, some musicians tried to create a music theory that could predict with mathematical power whether music would sound good. This seemed like a good-faith experiment at the time, but in retrospect, there was a subtext, intended or not, of finding a way to claim that non-western music was objectively bad and harmful.

This video essay from YouTube bassist Adam Neely goes into some of this history:

(Content warning: discussions of racial topics)

From this embarrassing history, we have the unfortunate legacy of well-meaning musicians like yourself feeling afraid of experimenting with the boundaries of music theory. Your question indicates that you are genuinely nervous that using non-functional harmony will ruin the artistic value of your music, but the fact that you're still asking the question is proof that it's something your heart and your ear are urging you to try anyway. I encourage you to reject the unfortunate parts of your music heritage that trap you in a straightjacket. Embrace the much longer and much richer tradition of music being about self-expression and the joyful exploration of sound. Feel free to push boundaries, experiment with the rules, and develop your own personal palette of musical ideas that resonate with you. And when you use music theory, use it as a tool to expand your horizons, not to limit yourself to what others have decreed acceptable.

Comment: I think I've read about a more modern version that tries to predict with mathematical power how *catchy* a piece is instead. I also think I've read that the modern version is shockingly accurate.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I am very skeptical. Call Me Crazy, Hey Jude, It Don't Mean a Thing (If It Ain't Got That Swing), and Sandstorm by Darude are all catchy songs, but they come from completely different musical traditions and use completely different music theory. If you mean that chart toppers use music theory, well, yes, they do. But they are also produced with teams of highly experienced musicians being given millions of dollars to come up with music for the explicit purpose of selling well. Of _course_ the music they make is going to be catchy!